# Concise Grading

Tags: code-golf

Write a program or a function in your favorite programming language that will take as input a number `n` (integer or non-integer) between `0` and `100` inclusive, and output the corresponding grade as outlined below:

- If `0 < n <= 40`, then output `E`.
- If `40 < n <= 55`, then output `D`.
- If `55 < n <= 65`, then output `C`.
- If `65 < n <= 70`, then output `C+`.
- If `70 < n <= 75`, then output `B-`.
- if `75 < n <= 80`, then output `B`.
- If `80 < n <= 85`, then output `B+`.
- If `85 < n <= 90`, then output `A-`.
- If `90 < n <= 95`, then output `A`.
- If `95 < n <= 100`, then output `A+`.

You are guaranteed that there are no other cases to test, and that `n` is guaranteed to be within `0` and `100`.

The input `n` can be provided via `stdin` or as an argument to the program.

Lines in the output are **not** allowed to have trailing spaces and/or newlines. You must output **exactly** the corresponding grade, nothing else.

Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Odd, I've never received an `E` grade before... Is that for ease of coding, or did you intend `F`?

Comment: @StevenH. I actually do mean `E` there (that's how my university denotes failing grades).

Comment: Some education systems use E as the absolute lowest without an F

Comment: I think we've already had a challenge to convert numbers grades to letters.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>74</s> <s>66</s> 73 bytes

```
lambda n,l="E "*8+"D D D C C C+ B- B B+ A- A A+ A+":l.split()[int(n-1)/5]
```

Unnamed lambda, uses a list of all grades in groups of 5. (I'm sure there's a way to handle n=100 without adding the extra 'A+' at the end, I'm just not sure how)

Edit: Thanks to @LeakyNun for 8 bytes

Comment: Question says n could be non-integer?

Comment: Logically you shouldn't have to add an extra `A+` at the end. This gives wrong output for `95.1`

Comment: Instead of doing `(n-1)/5`, you can do `20-n/5` which shifts thing correctly

Comment: @LeakyNun Could you post a fuller example of what you mean? Because substituting 20-n/5 still gives a bunch of weird behavior at "edge-numbers"

Comment: @Theo Have a look at Neil's answer.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, but he uses some fancy 'or' tricks to return 'E' when the index is outside the list bounds. I'm sure there is a way, but I don't know of a way to do this in python.

Comment: `lambda n,l="A+ A A- B+ B B- C+ C C D D D"+" E"*8:l.split()[int(20-n/5)]`

Comment: @LeakyNun That gives 'D' for 40, when it should be 'E' and so on

Comment: It gives me 'E' for 40 in both Python 2 and 3, although it doesn't work for other values in Python 2 because / is integer division. `*.2` works though.

Comment: @Neil Could you post the code you used? Because Leaky Nun's code doesn't run at all for values below 5, and mine gives wrong outputs for some values.

Comment: @LeakyNun's code worked for me in Python 3  for non-zero numbers; to make it work with zero I had to change `*8` to `*9`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```
n=>`A+ A A- B+ B B- C+ C C D D D`.split` `[20-n/5|0]||`E`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 36 bytes

```
?<Q41\E+C/-1075Q15?<Q66k-@"-+ "/_Q5d
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%3CQ41%5CE%2BC%2F-1075Q15%3F%3CQ66k-%40%22-%2B+%22%2F_Q5d&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%0A96%0A95.1%0A95%0A91%0A90%0A86%0A85%0A81%0A80%0A76%0A75%0A71%0A70%0A66%0A65%0A56%0A55%0A41%0A40%0A1&debug=0)

#### Explanation

Here is the equivalent program in Python 3.

```python
lambda Q:[chr(int(1075-Q)//15)+["-+ "[int(99-Q/5)%3],""][Q<66],"E"][Q<41].split()[0]
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/oRPSOB)